# Getting Item from list and then Writing its variables in console

Tags: c#, console.writeline

so first I generate items and then add them to a list.
But I have no idea how can I get that item back from the list 1 by 1 and states its Variables.
Here is the code for adding items to list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
      {
        public static Random Random = new Random();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
          int itemAmmount;
          Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of items you want.");
          itemAmmount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
          int DropRarity;
          int ItemCount;
          int i; 

          for(i = 0; i < itemAmmount; i++)
          {               
              DropRarity = Random.Next(1, 6);
              Items.Add(new Item(DropRarity, i));
          }
          for(int a = 0; a < itemAmmount;)
          {
            string Name1 = Items.Select(C => C.Name);
            int Damage =
            int Health =
            int Mana =
         }
    }
}
}
```

And here is the Code for item generator

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
class Item
{        
    public static string ID { get; set; }
    public static int Damage { get; set; }
    public static int Defense { get; set; }
    public static string Name;
    public static int HP, MANA;
    public static string Rarity;
    public static int NumberOfNames;
    public static string ItemType;
    public static Random Random = new Random();
    public static List<string> ItemTypeList = new List<string> { "Chest area armor", "Weapon", "Shield", "Head area armor", "Leggings", "Shoes", "Gloves", "Belt", "Ring" };
    public static List<string> WeaponList = new List<string> { "Staff", "Sword", "Dagger", "Wand", "Axe", "Mace" };
    public static string WeaponType;
    public static string Value;
    public static List<string> DamageType = new List<string> { "Meele", "Magic" };
    public static List<string> WeaponListMeele = new List<string> { "Staff", "Wand" };
    public static List<string> WeaponListMagic = new List<string> { "Sword", "Dagger", "Axe", "Mace" };
    public static List<string> ValuePoor = new List<string> { "Wooden", "Bronze" };
    public static List<string> ValueCommon = new List<string> { "Bronze", "Iron" };
    public static List<string> Value2 = new List<string> { "Silver", "Steel", "Iron" };
    public static List<string> ValueElite = new List<string> { "Silver", "Steel", "Dragon Glass", "Adamantium", "Titanium", "Arcane" };
    public static List<string> ValueLegendary = new List<string> { "Dragon Glass", "Adamantium", "Titanium", "Arcane" };
    public static List<string> ArmorValuePoor = new List<string> { "Cloth", "Leather" };
    public static List<string> ArmorValueCommon = new List<string> { "Cloth", "Leather", "Iron" };
    public static List<string> ArmorValue2 = new List<string> { "Iron", "Silver", "Steel" };
    public static List<string> ArmorValueElite = new List<string> { "Silver", "Steel", "Titanium", "Arcane", "Dragon Glass", "Titanium" };
    public static List<string> ArmorValueLegendary = new List<string> { "Titanium", "Arcane", "Dragon Glass", "Adamantium" };
    public static List<string> Name1 = new List<string> { "Stupid", "Great", "Powerful", "Epic", "Masterfull", "Mighty", "Bountiful", "Foreverlasting", "Pointless", "Useless" };
    public static List<string> Name2 = new List<string> { "Things", "Power", "Proportions", "Torment", "Legs", "Turnament", "Shit", "Crazyness", "Awesomeness" };
    public static List<string> NameLenght3List = new List<string> { "Ragnarok", "Power", "Bondage", "Noobs", "Great Weakness", "Error", "404", "Torture", "SHIT STATS(No idea since I'm not good enough to programm stats based on names)", "The Dark Lord", "Emperor", "Monkey Kong", "I ran out of words", "Blablabla" };

    public Item(int droprarity, int i)
    {
        int dropRarity = droprarity;
        NumberOfNames = NumberOfNamesGenerator(dropRarity);
        Rarity = RarityGenerator(dropRarity);
        ItemType = ItemTypeGenerator();
        if (ItemType == "Sword")
        {
            WeaponType = DamageType[Random.Next(0, DamageType.Count)];

            if (ItemType == "Meele")
            {
                ItemType = WeaponListMeele[Random.Next(0, WeaponListMeele.Count)];
            }
            else
            {
                ItemType = WeaponListMagic[Random.Next(0, WeaponListMagic.Count)];
            }
        }
        if (WeaponList.Contains(ItemType))
        {
            Value = WeaponValueGenerator(dropRarity);
            Damage = WeaponDamage(dropRarity);
        }
        else
        {
            Value = ArmorValueGenerator(dropRarity);
            HP = ArmorHealthGen(dropRarity);
            int RandomChance = Random.Next(0, 100);
            if (RandomChance <= 75)
            {
                MANA = ArmorManaGen(dropRarity);
            }
        }
        Name = NameGenerator();
        ID = i;


    }
    public static int IDGenerator
    public static string RarityGenerator(int dropRarity)
    {
        switch (dropRarity)
        {
            case 1:
                Rarity = "Poor";
                break;
            case 2:
                Rarity = "Common";
                break;
            case 3:
                Rarity = "Uncommon";
                break;
            case 4:
                Rarity = "Elite";
                break;
            case 5:
                Rarity = "Rare";
                break;
            case 6:
                Rarity = "Legendary";
                break;
        }

        return Rarity;
    }
    public static string ItemTypeGenerator()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}", ItemTypeList[Random.Next(0, ItemTypeList.Count)]);
    }
    public static int NumberOfNamesGenerator(int dropRarity)
    {
        switch (dropRarity)
        {
            case 1:
                NumberOfNames = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 4);
                break;
            case 3:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 4);
                break;
            case 4:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 5);
                break;
            case 5:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 5);
                break;
            case 6:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 6);
                break;
        }
        return NumberOfNames;
    }
    public static string NameGenerator()
    {
        int nameNR = NumberOfNames;
        if (nameNR == 2)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Rarity, Value, ItemType);
        }
        else if (nameNR == 3)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} of {2} {3}", Rarity, Value, ItemType, NameLenght3List[Random.Next(0, NameLenght3List.Count)]);
        }
        else if (nameNR == 4)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} of {2} {3} {4}", Rarity, Value, ItemType, Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name2[Random.Next(0, Name2.Count)]);
        }
        else if (nameNR == 5)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} of {2} {3} {4} {5}", Rarity, Value, ItemType, Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name2[Random.Next(0, Name2.Count)]);
        }
        else if (nameNR == 6)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} of {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}", Rarity, Value, ItemType, Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name2[Random.Next(0, Name2.Count)]);
        }
        else
        {
            string ErrorSword = "Error Sword/Armor/blablabla";
            return ErrorSword;
        }
    }
    public static string WeaponValueGenerator(int droprarity)
    {
        switch (droprarity)
        {
            case 1:
                Value = ValuePoor[Random.Next(0, ValuePoor.Count)];
                break;
            case 2:
                Value = ValueCommon[Random.Next(0, ValueCommon.Count)];
                break;
            case 3:
                Value = Value2[Random.Next(0, Value2.Count)];
                break;
            case 4:
                Value = ValueElite[Random.Next(0, ValueElite.Count)];
                break;
            case 5:
                Value = ValueElite[Random.Next(0, ValueElite.Count)];
                break;
            case 6:
                Value = ValueLegendary[Random.Next(0, ValueLegendary.Count)];
                break;

        }
        return Value;
    }

    public static string ArmorValueGenerator(int droprarity)
    {
        switch (droprarity)
        {
            case 1:
                Value = ArmorValuePoor[Random.Next(0, ArmorValuePoor.Count)];
                break;
            case 2:
                Value = ArmorValueCommon[Random.Next(0, ArmorValueCommon.Count)];
                break;
            case 3:
                Value = ArmorValue2[Random.Next(0, ArmorValue2.Count)];
                break;
            case 4:
                Value = ArmorValueElite[Random.Next(0, ArmorValueElite.Count)];
                break;
            case 5:
                Value = ArmorValueElite[Random.Next(0, ArmorValueElite.Count)];
                break;
            case 6:
                Value = ArmorValueLegendary[Random.Next(0, ArmorValueLegendary.Count)];
                break;

        }
        return Value;
    }

    public static int WeaponDamage(int droprarity)
    {
        switch (droprarity)
        {
            case 1:
                Damage = Random.Next(5, 20);
                break;
            case 2:
                Damage = Random.Next(25, 45);
                break;
            case 3:
                Damage = Random.Next(50, 105);
                break;
            case 4:
                Damage = Random.Next(110, 200);
                break;
            case 5:
                Damage = Random.Next(210, 500);
                break;
            case 6:
                Damage = Random.Next(550, 1200);
                break;
        }
        return Damage;
    }

    public static int ArmorHealthGen(int droprarity)
    {
        switch (droprarity)
        {
            case 1:
                HP = Random.Next(5, 20);
                break;
            case 2:
                HP = Random.Next(25, 45);
                break;
            case 3:
                HP = Random.Next(50, 105);
                break;
            case 4:
                HP = Random.Next(110, 200);
                break;
            case 5:
                HP = Random.Next(210, 500);
                break;
            case 6:
                HP = Random.Next(550, 1200);
                break;
        }
        return HP;
    }

    public static int ArmorManaGen(int droprarity)
    {
        switch (droprarity)
        {
            case 1:
                MANA = Random.Next(5, 20);
                break;
            case 2:
                MANA = Random.Next(25, 45);
                break;
            case 3:
                MANA = Random.Next(50, 105);
                break;
            case 4:
                MANA = Random.Next(110, 200);
                break;
            case 5:
                MANA = Random.Next(210, 500);
                break;
            case 6:
                MANA = Random.Next(550, 1200);
                break;
        }
        return MANA;
    }
}
```

}
enter code here

Comment: If you want **each** Item instance to have its **own, unique stats**, then the members that apply to a specific instance of Item **cannot be `static`**.  For instance, `static string ID` would need to be `string ID`.  You're going to need to change much of your Item class to deal with these changes!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Foreach

```
foreach(var item in items) 
{ 
//here you can get item one by one
}
```

Comment: I know how to call them all out,but what I want to do is see their value in console. Thats what I have problem with.

Comment: You must delete "static" from Item class, see Idle_Mind comment.